# Restify middleware like express middleware specifying route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, restify

I need to use restify middleware system just like express middleware, but it doesn't seem to work since restify needs only a callback when using

```
server.use(callback)
```

Express allows us to make something like :

```
server.use(patternConcerned, callback)
```

So, when the request will match the patternConcerned, the server will execute the middleware call.

Does it exist something similar using restify ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Restify do not allow the creation of sub-application.

You're code doesn't work because Restify `server.use(callback)` instantiate a new middleware on your entire application while Express `server.use(patternConcerned, callback)` instantiate a new middleware on a sub-application.

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply. So, how can I do to manage acces rights, like using role management ?

Comment: If your function has to be called on each route, use server.use(callback), it should work. If It's only for some route, create a middleware manage(res, req, next) and call it everywhere it has to be, without forgetting to call next() at the end.

Comment: What's the best way to do something like this?
https://gist.github.com/augustovictor/bfcfe4b0824d73ecfb7ecac336bc83ac